# How to make bottom fixed view in flutter

Tags: flutter

How to make the fixed bottom view in flutter like below example (it is don with android java,xml)
[image: flutter bottom fixed layout]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve it by below widget tree, I will give you basic Idea.

```
- Container 
 - Column 
  - Expanded(ListView)
  - Container - Height: 50, Width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
     - Row (Your children widgets)
```